# Massive NuGet Package Manager Crash in VS 2019

Tags: c#, xamarin, package, nuget

I'm busy with a iOS / Android hybrid app using Xamarin Forms. I want to add a package that I need to complete my solution but Visual Studio crashes dismally when I try and access the NuGet package manager. I post this here because I think this might be related to a VS 2019 update. Has anyone experienced this problem? Any workarounds or insights?

I've tried editing the project and adding package references manually. They appear to just show an yellow warning and never load.

```
<PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile" Version="2.4.1" />
<PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" Version="2.4.1" />
```

Here's the error that VS produces - it looks like NuGet is broken perhaps.

[image: Visual Studio Error]

Comment: That usually suggests that something went wrong at installation time. 
Did you update recently?

You should try repairing your Visual Studio installation.

Comment: Thanks - I'm repairing the VS installation right now I'll let you know how it goes. FYI - I ran a VS update yesterday

Comment: Ok - it seems something went wrong with the VS update - after a repair the nuget package manager starts up. So anyone seeing this should go back to the installer and repair. The ol' switching it on and off again.